# Composing two ActionBuilders in Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have controllers that I'd like to call like this

```
def getSensitiveData = Authenticated.hasPermissions(Permissions.ADMIN).async { 
  implicit request =>
    Future.successful(Ok)
  }
}
```

and like this

```
def getLessSensitiveData = Authenticated.async { implicit request =>
  Future.successful(Ok)
}
```

where Authenticated is an ActionBuilder that inspects the request for some authorization logic. I'd like Authenticated to have a method that allows me to add some further constraints to the authorization logic, or ideally, after the auth logic has pulled the user out of the database, it does further checks to make sure the user actually has the permissions we expect.

Unfortunately, I'm constrained to not using wrapped requests, but I am wondering how I can implement the method chaining to change the default behavior of the invoke block, or two potentially compose another action. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I gave up on this....ActionBuilders don't seem to be as handy as they look but building methods like these

def hasPermissions[A](permissions: Permissions*)(block: User => Future[SimpleResult])
                          (implicit request: Request[A]) : Future[SimpleResult]

is easy and composes rather nicely, though you may find yourself with lots of brackets and indentation.